# Intel XDK QRCode Scanning Issue

Tags: web, qr-code, intel

So am trying to use the barcode scanner in XDK and it WORKS except when am scanning a QRCode that contains more than one line of plain text.

For example:
If this is in the QRCode:

```
hey you
```

It gets scanned without any issues

BUT if this is in the QRCode:

```
hey
you
```

It fails. The app reacts as if nothing was scanned. Nothing is outputted.

My Code:

```
function scan(){
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan",function(evt){
            intel.xdk.notification.beep(1);
            if (evt.success === true) {
                    //successful scan
                    //console.log(evt.codedata);
                    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = String(evt.codedata); 
            }else {
                    //failed scan
                    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Scan Operation Failed";
            }
    },false);
    intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode();
}
```

I really hope you guys help me. If the XDK's QRCode scanner is just not capable of scanning multi-lines of plain text i will have to stop developing with XDK, which is a bummer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue, looks like it is a bug, I will log the issue, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up. This issue has now been fixed in our build system and the latest version of App Preview for Android, Windows Phone, and iOS. Please try your code again and let us know if you have any issues.